# Does Eidolon flight work as the fly spell for running?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, movement, flight, eidolon

I am playing a unchained summoner and took the [Inevitable](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/summoner-unchained/eidolons-unchained) Eidolon sub-type. At 4th level it becomes immune to fatigue and exhaustion. I have selected the fly evolution which grants the Eidolon a fly speed equal to its land speed.

Now there are two levels of flight possible for the Eidolon, first is non-magical which gives it wings, second is magical flight where the wings are not needed (but I assume can be kept for visual purposes and other evolutions?).

Since the first is non-magical flight, the [movement rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/exploration-movement#TOC-Movement) indicate that running is allowed. As it is immune to fatigue and exhaustion, it can also run without stopping so it have a much higher travel speed than most. However, the magical flight is less clear. I am unsure if the rules under [fly](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fly) now get applied or if its still considered normal movement. The spell does not get the ability to run and Im trying to find out if somewhere that gets applied over to all magical flight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The flight evolution does not work like the Fly spell

Simply because it's magical flight, it does not mean that it works like the magical Fly spell, but that its a [Supernatural](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Supernatural-Abilities-Su-) ability. The evolution description is the following:

> [Flight](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/summoner-unchained/eidolons-unchained#TOC-2-Point-Evolutions) (Ex or Su): The eidolon grows large wings, like those of a bat, bird, insect, or dragon, gaining the ability to fly. The eidolon gains a fly speed equal to its base speed. The eidolon’s maneuverability depends on its size. Medium or smaller eidolons have good maneuverability. Large eidolons have average maneuverability, while Huge eidolons have poor maneuverability. For 2 additional evolution points, the eidolon flies by means of magic. It loses its wings, but its maneuverability increases to perfect. **If the eidolon flies by magic, this is a supernatural ability**. The eidolon can increase its fly speed by spending additional evolution points, gaining a 20-foot increase to its fly speed for each additional point spent. Requirements: Summoner level 5th.

Now, regardless of the ability type or the source of this flight speed, this has nothing to do with the Fly spell, which has specific rulings on how the spell works. If you check the [movement rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alignment-description/movement/), there is nothing that prevents a [flying creature](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alignment-description/movement#TOC-Fly) from taking the Hustle or Run movement types.

That restriction is specific to the Fly spell and does not affect any other source of flight that is not based on that spell.

However, flying creatures were allowed to run back in 3.5, because the monster manual *specifically* said so, but that rule reference is missing in Pathfinder, which confused some people. There is an [open FAQ request thread](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2q44n?Run-action-with-alternate-movement-modes#1) at Paizo's messageboards asking for official clarification on that topic.

Personally, I don't try to backtrack Pathfinder rules to 3.5 rules, unless the reason behind a rule is certainly mysterious, and as I read the rules now, a flying or swimming speed is no different from a land speed. While back in 3.5 you had to memorize or pick up the book to figure out if each creature could run or not.